# control shutter speed on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, nokia, imaging, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

Can the shutter speed be controlled on a windows phone?

I know Nokia has an Imaging SDK available for its LUMIA phones, not sure if somebody has tried to control shutter speed and if it is available to be controlled through the SDK?

Any guidance is appreciated?

Comment: [This Windows Phone app](http://www.wpcentral.com/oneshot-windows-phone-8-first-app-show-power-nokia-imaging-sdk) is claimed to be able to set shutter speed, so apparently the answer is Yes.

Comment: Are you doing it on the managed level or on the native level?

Answer (score 0):

Nokia Imaging SDK doesn't support controlling the shutter speed, at least not on the C# level. It might be possible on the native level, but it will most likely be very complex.

[Here is a msdn page regarding controlling the advanced photo capture options.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)